# Same Python code, same Data, outcomes different if Data imported or not?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a Python code that first aggregates and standardizes Data into a file I called "tripFile". Then the code tries to identify the differences between this most recent tripFile and a previous one.

From the first part of the code, if I export the tripFile, and import it again for the second part of the code, it takes around 5 minutes to run and says it is looping over a bit more than 4,000 objects.

`newTripFile = pd.read_csv(PATH + today + ' Trip File v6.csv')`

However, if I do not export & re-import the Data (just keeping it from the first part of the code), it takes a bit less than 24 hours (!!) and says it is looping over a bit more than 951,691 objects.

`newTripFile = tripFile`

My Data is a dataframe, and checked the shape of it, it is identical to the file I export.

Any idea what can be causing that ???

Here is the second part of my code:

```
oldTripFile = pd.read_excel(PATH + OLDTRIPFILE)
oldTripFile.drop(['id'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
oldTripFile['status'] = 'old'

# New version of trip file
newTripFile = pd.read_csv(PATH + today + ' Trip File v6.csv')
newTripFile.drop(['id'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
newTripFile['status'] = 'new'

db_trips = pd.concat([oldTripFile, newTripFile]) #concatenation of the two dataframes
db_trips = db_trips.reset_index(drop = True)
db_trips.drop_duplicates(keep = False, subset = [column for column in db_trips.columns[:-1] ], inplace = True)
db_trips = db_trips.reset_index(drop = True)
db_trips.head()
update_details = []

# Get the duplicates : only consider ['fromCode', 'toCode', 'mode'] for identifying duplicates
# Create a dataframe that contains only the trips that was deleted and was recently added
db_trips_delete_new = db_trips.drop_duplicates(keep = False, subset = ['fromCode', 'toCode', 'mode'])
db_trips_delete_new = db_trips_delete_new.reset_index(drop = True)

# New trips
new_trips = db_trips_delete_new[db_trips_delete_new['status'] == 'new'].values.tolist()
for trip in new_trips:
    trip.append('new trip added') 
update_details = update_details + new_trips


# Deleted trips
old_trips = db_trips_delete_new[db_trips_delete_new['status'] == 'old'].values.tolist()
for trip in old_trips:
    trip.append('trip deleted')
update_details = update_details + old_trips

db_trips_delete_new.head()

# Updated trips

# Ocean: no need to check the transit time column
sea_trips = db_trips.loc[db_trips['mode'].isin(['sea', 'cfs'])]
sea_trips = sea_trips.reset_index(drop = True)
list_trips_sea_update = sea_trips[sea_trips.duplicated(subset = ['fromCode', 'toCode', 'mode'], keep = False)].values.tolist()


if len(list_trips_sea_update) != 0:
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(list_trips_sea_update) - 1)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list_trips_sea_update)):
            if list_trips_sea_update[i][2] == list_trips_sea_update[j][2] and list_trips_sea_update[i][9] == list_trips_sea_update[j][9] and list_trips_sea_update[i][14] == list_trips_sea_update[j][14]:
                update_comment = ''
                
                # Check display from / to
                if list_trips_sea_update[i][5] != list_trips_sea_update[j][5]:
                    update_comment = update_comment + 'fromDisplayLocation was updated.'
                if list_trips_sea_update[i][12] != list_trips_sea_update[j][12]:
                    update_comment = update_comment + 'toDisplayLocation was updated.'
                
                # Get the updated trip (the row with status new)
                if list_trips_sea_update[i][17] == 'new' and list_trips_sea_update[j][17] != 'new' :
                    list_trips_sea_update[i].append(update_comment)
                    update_details = update_details + [list_trips_sea_update[i]]
                else:
                    if list_trips_sea_update[j][17] == 'new' and list_trips_sea_update[i][17] != 'new':
                        list_trips_sea_update[j].append(update_comment)
                        update_details = update_details + [list_trips_sea_update[j]]
                    else:
                        print('excel files are not organized')

# Ground: transit time column need to be checked
ground_trips = db_trips[~db_trips['mode'].isin(['sea', 'cfs'])]
ground_trips = ground_trips.reset_index(drop = True)
list_trips_ground_update = ground_trips[ground_trips.duplicated(subset = ['fromCode', 'toCode', 'mode'], keep = False)].values.tolist()

if len(list_trips_ground_update) != 0:
    for i in tqdm(range(0, len(list_trips_ground_update) - 1)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list_trips_ground_update)):
            if list_trips_ground_update[i][2] == list_trips_ground_update[j][2] and list_trips_ground_update[i][9] == list_trips_ground_update[j][9] and list_trips_ground_update[i][14] == list_trips_ground_update[j][14]:
                update_comment = ''
                
                # Check display from / to
                if list_trips_ground_update[i][5] != list_trips_ground_update[j][5]:
                    update_comment = update_comment + 'fromDisplayLocation was updated.'
                if list_trips_ground_update[i][12] != list_trips_ground_update[j][12]:
                    update_comment = update_comment + 'toDisplayLocation was updated.'
                
                # Check transit time
                if list_trips_ground_update[i][15] != list_trips_ground_update[j][15]:
                    update_comment = update_comment + 'transit time was updated.'
                
                # Get the updated trip (the row with status new)
                if list_trips_ground_update[i][17] == 'new' and list_trips_ground_update[j][17] != 'new' :
                    list_trips_ground_update[i].append(update_comment)
                    update_details=update_details + [list_trips_ground_update[i]]
                else:
                    if list_trips_ground_update[j][17] == 'new' and list_trips_ground_update[i][17] != 'new':
                        list_trips_ground_update[j].append(update_comment)
                        update_details = update_details + [list_trips_ground_update[j]]
                    else:
                        print('excel files are not organized')
```

And here an example of what my trip file looks like:

[image]

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ever it can be useful to someone else, issue was coming from the type. When keeping my tripFile in memory, one of my column was "10.0" for example, whereas when imported this column was "10".
As I'm comparing with another imported tripFile, if both files are imported the column in both files are of same type, but if one of the files is kept in memory the column is of different type in both files and considered as updated. As such takes much longer when kept in memory as every row is considered updated.